# Quarkus Kubernetes operator: how to set environment variables in application container (not operator container)?

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, application.properties, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-custom-resources

The Keycloak operator uses Quarkus: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/operator

In `application.properties` (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/operator/src/main/resources/application.properties) we can set environment variables:
https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes#environment-variables-from-keyvalue-pairs

For example:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.env.vars.kc-hostname=localhost
quarkus.kubernetes.env.vars.kc-proxy=edge
quarkus.kubernetes.env.vars.proxy-address-forwarding=true
```

In the Kubernetes manifests which are generated, these environment variables appear in the *operator* container:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            ...
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: localhost
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              value: "true"
            ...
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: edge
          image: keycloak/keycloak-operator:19.0.2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

However, I need them to be set in the *application* container, instead.

---

Here is another verification of this. The running operator container:

```
$ kubectl describe pod keycloak-operator --namespace=keycloak


Name:             keycloak-operator-6479dbc544-2wl4d
...
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/keycloak-operator-6479dbc544
Containers:
  keycloak-operator:
    Image:          keycloak/keycloak-operator:19.0.2
    ...
    Environment:
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE:      keycloak (v1:metadata.namespace)
      KC_HOSTNAME:               localhost
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING:  true
      OPERATOR_KEYCLOAK_IMAGE:   quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:nightly
      KC_PROXY:                  edge
```

and using the application manifest provided here (https://www.keycloak.org/operator/basic-deployment#_deploying_keycloak) here is the running application pod:

```
$ kubectl describe pod example-kc --namespace=keycloak

Name:             example-kc-0
Namespace:        keycloak
...
Containers:
  keycloak:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:nightly
    ...
    Environment:
      KC_CACHE_STACK:                 kubernetes
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED:              true
      KC_CACHE:                       ispn
      KC_DB:                          postgres
      KC_DB_URL_HOST:                 postgres-db
      KC_DB_USERNAME:                 <set to the key 'username' in secret 'keycloak-db-secret'>        Optional: false
      KC_DB_PASSWORD:                 <set to the key 'password' in secret 'keycloak-db-secret'>        Optional: false
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN:                 <set to the key 'username' in secret 'example-kc-initial-admin'>  Optional: false
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD:        <set to the key 'password' in secret 'example-kc-initial-admin'>  Optional: false
      jgroups.dns.query:              example-kc-discovery.keycloak
      KC_HOSTNAME:                    test.keycloak.org
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE:      /mnt/certificates/tls.crt
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE:  /mnt/certificates/tls.key
      KC_PROXY:                       passthrough
```

Modifying the manifest (https://www.keycloak.org/operator/basic-deployment#_deploying_keycloak) to replace `hostname: test.keycloak.org` with `hostname: localhost` *does* work. But how about for the other environment variables `KC_PROXY` and `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING`? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `unsupported` resource property. For instance:

```
apiVersion: k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
 ...
spec:
  unsupported:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: keycloak
            env:
              - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
                value: "true"
```

See `kubectl explain Keycloak.spec.unsupported.podTemplate`

> ```
> KIND:     Keycloak
> VERSION:  k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
>
> RESOURCE: podTemplate <Object>
>
> DESCRIPTION:
>      You can configure that will be merged with the one configured by default by the operator. 
>      ...
>      
> FIELDS:   
>      metadata <Object>
>
>      spec <Object>
> ```

Comment: Worked for older version of KC CRDs (esp. 19). WIth more recent version, you can try tweaking the args field (unsupported.podTemplate.spec.containers[0].args=["start", "--proxy=edge"]) or even use spec.additionalOptions (name=proxy, value=edge)